# Zend Framework Date to MySQL

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form-element, zendx

Hi i'm using zendx form element date picker

```
$datadinascita = new ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_DatePicker('datadinascita');
$datadinascita->setLabel('Data di nascita:')
    ->setJQueryParam('dateFormat', 'dd-mm-yy')
    ->setJQueryParam('changeYear', 'true')
    ->setJqueryParam('changeMonth', 'true')
    ->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Date(array('format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy')))
    ->setRequired(true);
```

I would convert date dd-mm-yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd to insert in mysql.
After that how i can re-convert the new date to original date for using that again?

Comment: You're going to want to use PHP's date functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the standard PHP `date` and `strtotime` functions:

```
<?php
$mysqlDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($datadinascitaDate);
$datadinascitaDate = date('d-m-y', strtotime($mysqlDate);
```